# How to clean up files in a systemd privatetmp tmp folder

Tags: systemd, cleanup, tmp

I am supporting a Web App that writes files to /tmp. This runs in Nginx via systemd with the default nginx systemd config file that has PrivateTmp=yes set. That makes a private systemd-private-* folder which has a tmp folder under it. When it try to configure systemd-tmpfiles to clean up that folder it can't find it. Anyone have experience with how to get around this?

Thank You,
Kevin Runde